# How to return a dataframe with an added column without overwriting the previous dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a dataframe that is equal to an existing dataframe with an added column.
For example, say I have an existing dataframe df1, and I want to create a new dataframe df2 that is just df1 with a new column of 3s. How could I do in Pandas so without affecting df1 at all?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df2 = df1.assign(newcol=3)
```

`assign`, as with most methods in pandas, `inplace` is set to False, therefore a copy of df1 is created with the results.  Therefore, you can assign the results of this operation a new variable and df1 is untouched.